# Closed form solution for linear dynamical systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, self-learning, closed-form

The [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_dynamical_system) page about linear dynamical systems says:

> linear dynamical systems can be solved exactly

But from what I've found on the web, in the case of linear time-varying dynamical system (e.g. $\mathbf x'=\mathbf A(t)\mathbf x(t)$, where $\mathbf x$ is a n-dimensional state vector and $\mathbf A$ a $n*n$ time varying matrix) a closed form solution is very rare.

Which one of the two sentences is true?

Comment: Both are correct, you have written yourself "in the case of linear time-varying dynamical system". The link is about linear equations with a constant matrix.

Comment: Thank you @JohnB. I have noticed this. But does it mean that _linear time-varying dynamical systems_ are NOT a subclass of _linear dynamical systems_?

Comment: Ah, they should have written something like "autonomous linear dynamical systems" in wikipedia. These are a subclass of "linear time-varying dynamical systems". Note that when we write "time-varying" we are saying that it may be time-varying, not that it is.